# Why doesn't my game correctly display "Package picked up" when I go over the gameObject marked trigger and tagged "Package"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

When I drive over the trigger, I get no response in the console. On the Package I have Rigidbody2D, Collision Script, Collider 2D and it is marked as trigger. On the car I have a Collider 2D, Rigidbody 2D adn my movement script. I am very new to coding so my baby eyes cant tell whats wrong :(

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    Debug.Log("Oof!");   
}
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Package"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Package picked up");
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This collision script is comparing the object it collides with has the tag "Package".

> if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Package"))

From what you told me, this script is currently on the package object. So it's a package checking if its colliding with another "Package"...

**Solution is to move the script to the car**, since is the car that will be colliding with the package.

PS.: It should only log the "Package picked up" message if it meets the "if" condition. Is the package tag "Package"?

Comment: This worked, thank you so much!!! The small q's count, I'll know all this stuff like the back of my hand soon and it's because of Heros like you!!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Just vote this answear up and select it as the best one, so it has a green checkmark on your topic and it'll be tagged as solved.